# How to update MalwareBytes on user machines that don't have admin rights?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, malwarebytes

I run a Windows 10 shop. All user PCs have MalwareBytes installed and have in the MalwareBytes settings to auto-update every day. However, the users must be admins to install these updates and therefore the updates never get installed.

I've looked at forums on how to configure MalwareBytes to install updates without needing admin rights but there doesn't seem to be a solution. Could someone recommend a solution?

### Solution

Use task scheduler to schedule an administrative task to run the update. Command to run the update is `mbam.exe /runupdate`. Just go to the directory where you have MalwareBytes installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Task (Task Scheduler) to run Malwarebytes daily.  Use the settings to give this task Elevated Permissions and set to run daily. You (or an administrator) needs to OK the task to save it.

But then it will run daily for standard users.

Most AntiVirus apps can be set to run this way.

Comment: I like the idea, it makes sense. The problem is MalwareBytes has no problem running, just updating. I'm not sure where to point the action of the task to do the updates. The only update file in the directory is `UpdateControllerImpl.dll`.

Comment: Point the task to the Malwarebytes definition Updater app. That should work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which `.exe` this would be in the directory. The names aren't descriptive and all abbreviated. Do you have any experience with MalwareBytes and know what the executable would be called?

Comment: It may be a parameter in the main program and so you would need to call it with that parameter.  https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/258597-application-updates/

Comment: Forgot about command flags, now I just need to figure out the flag. Thanks for you help.

Comment: This seems to be the command `mbam.exe /runupdate`. Thanks again John.

Comment: That should be true as well and that string can go in the Task setup